# Error while trying to connect aws ec2 linux instance using git-bash on windows

Tags: amazon-ec2, git-bash

I'm trying to connect my Ec2 linux 2 server instance on windows using git bash. Every time I enter my code it says that my private key file is not accessible.

Since it was not working on one path I tried different path placing the key in different locations. Every time I get the same error.

```
$ ssh -i "path\keypair.pem" ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xx.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com
```

This is the error i get every time:

```
Warning: Identity file path\keypair.pem not accessible: No such file or directory.
user@ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xx.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com: 
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

This is my first time trying to work on aws linux 2. So please help me over come this issue.

Comment: you probably need double `\\\` as folder separator in path to your key

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AccessingInstancesLinux.html) in order to connect to your EC2.

```
ssh -i /path/my-key-pair.pem ec2-user@ec2-198-51-100-1.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

You are missing the user name for the ec2 instance.

> For Amazon Linux 2 or the Amazon Linux AMI, the user name is
> ec2-user.
>  For a CentOS AMI, the user name is centos.
>  For a
> Debian AMI, the user name is admin or root.
>  For a Fedora AMI, the
> user name is ec2-user or fedora.
>  For a RHEL AMI, the user name is
> ec2-user or root.
>  For a SUSE AMI, the user name is ec2-user or
> root.
>  For an Ubuntu AMI, the user name is ubuntu.
>  Otherwise,
> if ec2-user and root don't work, check with the AMI provider.